# How to use MotionLayout like TransitionManager?

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

Tutoiral I see with `MotionLayout` have things in common and that is it focused on either an `onClick` or `onSwipe` to trigger `MotionLayout` Transition. I was wondering how to Transition from something like State A to State B with other trigger like instead of `onClick` it would trigger `onNavDestinationChanged` something like:

```
navController.addNavigationChangeListener { motionLayout.transtionToAnotherState() }
```

Something similar to `TransitionManager` where if I want to go from `Scene A` to `Scene B` I just do:

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootLayout)
// Do someLayout changes
```

1) Is something similar doable with MotionLayout?
2) If yes can anyone guide me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently, it was really easy to do this and for anyone else who needs to know simply call:

```
motionLayout.transitionToState(constraintSetId)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no 100% same way to do it, but you can get similar result if you know your original and final states.

```
setTransition(R.id.stateA, R.id.stateB);
setTransitionDuration(durationMs); // optional
transitionToEnd(); // here may be transitionToStart to goto state A from B
```

If you don't know your current state you can read it from TransitionView itself:

```
getCurrentState();
```

but be aware, if you are in the middle of transition it will return -1

Comment: I did something similar to this. The issue was that state is ruined on rotation. The screen does not update properly after rotation.

Comment: Sorry, my app has no landscape mode, but I can guess that ML missing to save it's state in onSaveInstance callback. Did you try to recover proper state yourself?

Comment: apparently, the one i mentioned above is a bug on the lower version of the library. it is now fixed with 2.0.0-beta06